# How to read the .NET reflector --- for MemberShipProvider

Tags: .net, asp.net-membership, reflector

I am implementing the MembershipProvider. So I want to refer to the implementation of sqlMemberShipProvider by Microsoft in .NET reflector and find an interesting thing:

for RequiresQuestionAndAnswer, it retrieve value of _RequiresQuestionAndAnswer directly.

```
public override bool RequiresQuestionAndAnswer
{
    get
    {
        return this._RequiresQuestionAndAnswer;
    }
}
```

But where the _RequiresQuestionAndAnswer get the value? I think there must be some logic retrieve value from web.config, right? But I can't find. Why? Where is the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Version 6.6:

1. Click on the backing `_RequiresQuestionAndAnswer` field in the getter-body. This will take you to the field-declaration and highlight the field on the browser-panel.
2. Right-Click on the field on the browser-panel and choose **Analyze** on the context-menu.
3. Open up the **Assigned By** node from the analyzer-tree. Notice that the only method assigning to the field is the public `Initialize` method.
4. Right-click on  the method and choose **Go to Member** on the context-menu. You will see that this method assigns the field to the value of a call to `SecUtility.GetBooleanValue` with appropriate arguments.
5. For further information, investigate the implementation of this method by clicking on the method-call.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the `Initialize` method. Here's how the field is initialized:

```
this._RequiresUniqueEmail = SecUtility.GetBooleanValue(config, "requiresUniqueEmail", true);
```

So yes it is read from the config file.

Answer (score 0):

It is read from the web.config when the membership provider is initialized. It defaults to TRUE

Answer (score 0):

In reflector, choose disassemble the class it self. Then scroll to the bottom and click on Expend Methods.

Now you can search for this member and check who it's used.